# Automatically add css rule to flex items in Webpack

Tags: webpack, flexbox, create-react-app, postcss

I would like to add css rule `min-width:0` to all elements which are flex items -- have rule `display: flex`.

It helps to [prevent issues](https://dfmcphee.com/flex-items-and-min-width-0/) in flexbox. Is there a webpack or postcss plugin which allows this? I am using mainly [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) as a boilerplate project and styled components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pretty popular postcss plugin [postcss-flexbugs-fixes](https://github.com/luisrudge/postcss-flexbugs-fixes) that helps with some issues with flexbox.

Comment: I know this plugin. It doesn't add this rule into flex items.

Comment: then you can write your own postcss plugin which can detect if a ruleset has display: flex and if it doesn't have `min-width` property add `min-width: 0;`. This is something that can be easily done, here's a gist https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/d9884c426ffeaf8cd5744668393bbbd1/e004c4c40ef4a22f77652fef4be014c2a0e7a569

Comment: thank you. I was wondering if it is possible with only a postcss plugin or there is a solution for this. I think I will create a postcss plugin.